# Algebra problem with fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

"In a musical class, the students either played piano or violin as head instrument. By a concert, the students got to choose whether they would do a solo or pair-performance. A piano player can only play with a violin player and a violin player with a piano player. It turned out that $2/3$ of the students with piano as head instrument and $3/5$ of the students with violin as head instrument chose to perform in pair. How many performed solo?"

Thoughts: I've looked up the answer, it's $7/19$. I know that I can do this:

$0.33$% + $0.4$% = $0.73$%

$0.73$/$2$ = $36.5$%

And $7$/$19$ may be close to 36.5%, but I still don't know how to get the answer in fractions. I've tried dividing and more, but I need to know the logic behind my actions :) (my brain is tired right now). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from which group each fraction is referring to. The $\frac23$ refers to a fraction *out of just the piano players*, the $\frac35$ refers to a fraction *out of just the violin players*, and the answer you are looking for is a fraction *out of **all** the students*. Since the two original fractions are referring to different groups of students, you can't add them! It would be safest to work with the raw number of students.

Suppose $p$ is number of students that are piano players, and $v$ is the number students that are violin players.

Then the information says $\frac23 p$ piano players choose to play with $\frac35 v$ violin players. So we are left with $\frac13 p$ piano players who play solo and $\frac25 v$ violin players who play solo, for a total of $(\frac13 p + \frac25 v)$ students who play solo. We want to know what this is as a fraction of the total number of students.

Since each violin player plays with one piano player and vice versa, we know that $\frac23 p = \frac35 v$. We can multiply both sides of this equation by 3 and divide both sides by 2 to get $p = \frac9{10} v$.

Now the total number of solo students is 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac13 p + \frac25v &= \frac13\cdot\frac9{10}v +\frac25v\\
&= \frac3{10}v+\frac25v \\
&= \frac3{10}v+\frac4{10}v\\
&= \frac7{10}v
\end{align}
$$
Also, the total number of students is 
$$
\begin{align}
p+v &= \frac9{10}v + v \\
&= \frac9{10}v + \frac{10}{10}v \\
&= \frac{19}{10}v
\end{align}
$$

So the fraction of students playing solo is:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(\frac7{10}v)}{(\frac{19}{10}v)} &= \frac{(\frac7{10})}{(\frac{19}{10})}\\
&= \frac{7}{10}\cdot\frac{10}{19}\\
&= \frac{7}{19}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ah yes, your answer makes sense and I'm thankful for your explanation. Really, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it this way:

$$
0.33\%=\frac13,\qquad0.40\%=\frac25\\\\
$$

Then, we can add up these fractions:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac13 + \frac25&=\frac{5}{15}+\frac{6}{15}\\\\
&=\frac{11}{15}
\end{align}
$$

Now, we can divide that fraction by two by multiplying with $\frac12$:

$$
\frac{11}{15}\cdot\frac12=\frac{11}{30}
$$

But then, here we see that even with your method, our answer **does not**  match the one in your textbook. But, $\frac{11}{30}$ is still very close to $\frac{7}{19}$. It might be that you have to try a different method, or the textbook is wrong. Either way, I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is wrong, sorry.

Comment: I tried the same thing you did! But it wasn't the textbook's answer so I don't know.

Comment: @didnotcomeuptosomething Look at DavidButler's answer.